# Unity Selecting sub-model

Tags: inheritance, unity-game-engine, selection, raycasting

I have a model of human body which consists of hundreds of sub-models (muscles).

I want to click on the sub-model and get its name.

Basically, I know two possible solutions.

1. To create stupid script OnButtonDown for every single sub-model.. which is insane.
2. Create script using raycasting

I've tried the second one, didn't work for my sub-models.

As for the first one, I was thinking whether there is some kind of inheritance.. that I could move one script for Model and it would be applied on all its sub-models. I was trying to find the way to do that, but I have failed.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Do you have colliders on your sub models (ie the children Game Objects)?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all of your sub objects have colliders on them, and then create a javascript (unityscript) asset with the following code:

```
function Update () 
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1")) 
    {
        var ray : Ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);
        var hit : RaycastHit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, hit)) 
        {
            Debug.Log(hit.collider.gameObject.name);
            Destroy(hit.collider.gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

Attach this to an object that is always alive (like the main camera).

Comment: Thank you, but I have another problem here. Now I have selected the game object, but even though I am trying to change its material (color), it does not work. Because the texture is mapped on several sub models at once.

Comment: Probably best to ask this as a separate question, with a little more detail.